# Nearby Notifications is Temporarily Muted

Tags: android, eddystone, google-nearby

On the Nearby Notifications page (developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview), I found this: "Due to an issue that was discovered late in the development cycle, the Nearby Notifications feature will be temporarily muted for consumers beginning around September 21, 2016."

The phrase "for consumers beginning around" is confusing. Does this mean new Android users or all users who haven't enabled Nearby Discoveries?

While I was all set to launch a business use case leveraging Nearby Notifications, this came as a shocking for me. This message leaves Nearby Notifications highly unreliable for any commercial use case even in future. Least expected from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is that notifications are disabled for everyone, effective now (October 2016), and will not be restored until at least the next release of Google Play Services has been pushed out.  My guess is that folks will not have notifications unmuted until/unless they upgrade to this new version of Google Play Services.

Here's a link to the page that talks about the outage: https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview

Comment: This makes sense. Notification on my Redmi Note 3 stopped showing and I was bit confused as why this this is happening. It seems the outage would take months to end. :(